# Product search Query from multiple model

Tags: sql, ajax, laravel

I have Two database table one is product and another is product-stock. I need to search product with name, barcode and SKU. The problem is product SKU in product stock table. How can I manage that things.

```js
// $productSku = ProductStock::where('product_id',$product->id)->first();
$product = Product::where('name', 'LIKE', $request->keyword.'%')
    /* ->orWhere($productSku, 'LIKE', $request->keyword.'%') */
    ->orWhere('barcode', 'LIKE', $request->keyword.'%')
    ->orderby('id','desc')
    ->get();

$output = '';

if (count($product) > 0) 
{
    $output = '<ul class="list-group">';
    
    foreach ($product as $row)
    {
        $output .= '<li class="list-group-item"  onclick="addProductCart('.$row->id.')" >';
        $output .= '<div class="product d-flex align-items-center">';

        $output .= '<div class="img mr-2">';
        $output .= '<img src="'.uploaded_asset($row->thumbnail_img).'" width="30" alt="Product Image">';
        $output .= '</div>';

        $output .= ' <div class="pro-nam">'.$row->name.'</div></div></li></ul>';
    }
}
else
{
    $output = '<ul class="list-group">';
    $output .= '<li class="list-group-item">'.'No results'.'</li>';
    $output .= '</ul>';
}

return $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's probably an SQL approach to this but what I usually do in such situations is create an empty array, then get the necessary primary data from the DB, in this case products, then loop over this data to get individual IDs using a for or foreach loop. So when you get the ID use it to query the secondary data, in this case product-stock (I'm assuming you're using the product id on this table to relate the two?) and place them in a temporary array which is then pushed to the main one. Example below:

```
$productData = array(); // Empty main array
$products = Product::all();

foreach ($products as $product) {
$id = $product->id; // Get the ID of the product
$stock = ProductStock::select('sku')->where('product_id', $id)->get();
$tempArray = [
'id' => $id,
'name' => $product->name,
'barcode' => $product->barcode,
'sku' => $stock->SKU]
array_push($productData, $tempArray); // Creates nested arrays in the main array
}
```

Keep in mind you may need to edit the collection targeting but that should do it. To get the data just loop over the main array. There may be a way to do this with SQL though, so this is just in case you're in a hurry or don't care.